# How to set order increment id iterator in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, sales-order, increment-id

Is there possible for magento 1 to increase order id each time plus 4.

Ex.

**My current order is 10001 and when we placed next time order from store next id would be 10005, after another next time it would be 10009.**

Each time order increment id will be +4 from current order id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you implement your own **increment model**

From my blog post on [increment models](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/12/magento-tutorial-use-increment-models-generate-ids-or-skus/):

> ### Writing Custom Increment Models
>
> You can specify any class as increment model that implements
>   `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Interface`. **Be aware:** This interface
>   pretents to only need one method, `getNextId()`, but at least the
>   following setters will be called as well:
>
> - setPrefix
> - setPadLength
> - setPadChar
> - setLastId
> - setEntityTypeId
> - setStoreId
>
> Yeah, Magento doesn’t give much love to interfaces. So if you want to
>   implement your own increment model, you should at least inherit from
>   `Varien_Object`, better from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract`
>   which already provides you with the prefix and padding logic.
>
> In the method `getNextId()` you will then generate the next increment id
>   based on the last one, that is accessible with `$this->getLastId()`

So in your case this would be:

```
class Stack_Model_Entity_IncrementStep extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract
{
    const STEP = 4;
    public function getNextId()
    {
        $last = $this->getLastId();
        if (strpos($last, $this->getPrefix()) === 0) {
            $last = (int)substr($last, strlen($this->getPrefix()));
        } else {
            $last = (int)$last;
        }
        $next = $last + self::STEP;
        return $this->format($next);
    }
}
```

This is mostly copied from [Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Increment/Numeric.php)  where it is `+1` instead of `+ self::STEP`.
You probably want to replace the constant in this minimum example with a configuration value.

Then update `increment_model` for orders in the `eav_entity_type` table and change it from `eav/entity_increment_numeric` to your model (e.g. `stack/entity_incrementStep`)

Comment: :facepalm: obviously that was so easy ^^ lol totally missed the fact that the class is stored in the DB too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that **Magento does not use the MySQL autoincrement for the increment id.**

The **increment ids are stored in the `eav_entity_store`** and incremented by a class.

For numeric increment, the class is `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric` and the method that takes care of the increment is `getNextId` :

```
public function getNextId()
{
    $last = $this->getLastId();

    if (strpos($last, $this->getPrefix()) === 0) {
        $last = (int)substr($last, strlen($this->getPrefix()));
    } else {
        $last = (int)$last;
    }

    $next = $last+1;

    return $this->format($next);
}
```

I could suggest that **you rewrite that class to replace this line**:

```
$next = $last+1;
```

With:

```
$next = $last+4;
```

However, **that will also affect the invoices, shipments and credit memos increment ids.**

Comment: i want to do only for order, without invoice,shipments and credit memos, Is there possible for that?

Comment: @Rakesh it's definitely possible but requires way more work and I'm not too sure how to work it out

Comment: Not so much work, if you know how ;) See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Magento set a order increment id from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` at function `_beforeSave()`.

If you would chnage at here then your problem will resolved

Comment: plz let me know for what to do inside _beforeSave() method?