# Add Dynamic Order Number Prefix [mm-yy-ordernumber]

Tags: magento2, orders, magento-2.0.7, increment-id

My client wants the current month and year as a prefix in order numbers. I have read many blogs but they are all for static prefix for order number.

I am looking for a solution in Magento 2.

Comment: have you done this?

Comment: @magentotwo No I am Not able to do this, do You have solution or you want solution for this ?

Comment: I want solution for this?

Comment: @magentotwo Sorry brother I am not able to find solution for this

Comment: @magentotwo You can ask new question and put this question link as reference may be someone help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a custom increment model.

You can read about increment models here: [How to set order increment id iterator in magento 1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134013/how-to-set-order-increment-id-iterator-in-magento-1/134019#134019)

In Magento 2, the implementation is still the same. In your case, you would extend `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue` and add a `getPrefix()` method to implement your custom prefix:

```
namespace Stack\OrderNumber\Model\Entity\Increment;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue;
class DatePrefix extends NumericValue
{
    public function getPrefix()
    {
        return \date('m-y');
    }
}
```

Then update `increment_model` for orders in the `eav_entity_type` table and change it from `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue` to your model (e.g. `Stack\OrderNumber\Model\Entity\Increment\DatePrefix`)

Comment: Does it actually works for you for Magento 2?
I've added breakpoints on all Increment* classes, created new one and set it for the order entity. The interpeter doesn't even walks into those classes.

Comment: You're right, it's different now, at least in Magento 2.2 Commerce. I recently had to look into it, will try to update the  answer accordingly. Remind me if I don't get back in the next days

Comment: Magento is so ambitious in concepts, then so badly driven... I've ended adding one more after plugin.