# Changing increment_model for orders

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, order-increment

i want to change default increment_model for orders only. I create new module and add new Class:

```php
Class Order extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\AbstractIncrement {
 ...
}
```

i updated table eav_entity_type ,the row with order in column instead of

```
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue
```

i've put

```
Vendor\OrderNumber\Model\Entity\Increment\Order
```

but this seems not working at all.

I put breakpoints in all increments classes and not single one are hit.

I find only this post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135109

But in comments i read that this will not work in magento >=2.2  ( i'm using 2.3 Commerce) .

Can someone help me find correct solution to this ?

### Edit - solution

My solution to this problem is to create new module:

/app/code/Vendor/OrderNumber

and add files:

/app/code/Vendor/OrderNumber/etc/di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote" type="Vendor\OrderNumber\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Quote" />
</config>
```

/app/code/Vendor/OrderNumber/etc/module.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_OrderNumber" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

/app/code/Vendor/OrderNumber/registration.php

```php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_OrderNumber',
    __DIR__
);
```

/app/code/Vendor/OrderNumber/Helper/Order.php

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\OrderNumber\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\{AbstractHelper, Context};
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as OrderCollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Order
 * @package Vendor\OrderNumber\Helper
 */
class Order extends AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var OrderCollectionFactory
     */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Order constructor.
     * @param OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }


    /**
     * @param $incrementId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHashedIncrementId($incrementId): string
    {
        $newIncrementId = $this->hash($incrementId);

        if ($this->isOrderIncrementIdExists($newIncrementId)) {
            $newIncrementId = $this->getHashedIncrementId($incrementId);
        }

        return $newIncrementId;
    }

    /**
     * @param $incrementId
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isOrderIncrementIdExists($incrementId): bool
    {
        $orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId)
            ->getSelect()->reset('columns');
        $orderCollection->getSelect()->columns('entity_id');

        return $orderCollection->getFirstItem()->getId() ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $oldIncrementId
     * @return int
     */
    private function hash($oldIncrementId)
    {
        $newIncrementId = 0;
        $oldIncrementId = (int)$oldIncrementId;

        // doing stuff with $oldIncrementId;

        return $newIncrementId;
    }
}
```

/app/code/Vendor/OrderNumber/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Quote.php

```php
<?php

namespace Strix\OrderNumber\Model\ResourceModel\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot;
use Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Manager;
use Vendor\OrderNumber\Helper\Order as OrderHelper;

/**
 * Class Quote
 * @package Vendor\OrderNumber\Model\ResourceModel\Quote
 */
class Quote extends \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote
{
    /**
     * @var OrderHelper
     */
    private $orderHelper;

    /**
     * Quote constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Snapshot $entitySnapshot
     * @param RelationComposite $entityRelationComposite
     * @param Manager $sequenceManager
     * @param OrderHelper $orderHelper
     * @param string $connectionName
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Snapshot $entitySnapshot,
        RelationComposite $entityRelationComposite,
        Manager $sequenceManager,
        OrderHelper $orderHelper,
        $connectionName = null
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $entitySnapshot, $entityRelationComposite, $sequenceManager, $connectionName);
        $this->orderHelper = $orderHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReservedOrderId($quote)
    {
        return $this->orderHelper->getHashedIncrementId(parent::getReservedOrderId($quote));
    }

}
```

This solution worked for me and i can modify order number in the way i want.

Comment: do you want to add static prefix/postfix in order increment number or dynamic?

Comment: i wan't to complety change the way increment number is generated so i think best will be dynamic.